# Plotting a network using ggplot using data from one file and color coding using another

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a problem most likely with a simple solution. I have two data frames. The first is a simple edge list with weights that looks like this:

```
head(merge_allwinsloss_df)

winner loser weight
1    CAL   HAW     20
2   TENN   APP      7
3    LOU  CHAR     56
4    CMU   PRE     46
5   WAKE  TULN      4
6    CIN   UTM     21
```

and the second is a file that provides groupings (in the form of college football conferences) that looks like this:

```
 short conference
1   TEM        AAC
2   USF        AAC
3   UCF        AAC
4   CIN        AAC
5   ECU        AAC
6  CONN        AAC
```

What I'd like to do is to create a plot (preferably using ggplot) that uses a directed graph (from winner to loser), weight the edges (via weight) and color those by teams in the same conference, and color code nodes by conference. The code below is a "start" but I'm not really getting anywhere.

```
ggplot(data = merge_allwinsloss_df, aes(from_id = winner, to_id = loser)) +
  geom_net(aes(color = all_teams_by_conference_df), layout.alg = "fruchtermanreingold", 
           size = 2, labelon = TRUE, vjust = -0.6, ecolour = "grey80",
           directed = TRUE, fontsize = 3, ealpha = 0.5) +
  scale_color_brewer("Conference",
                     palette = "Paired") +
  xlim(c(-0.05, 1.05)) +
  theme_net() +
  theme(legend.position = "bottom")
```

I melted the data but that also caused a lot of other problems mostly associated with either losing the mapping or my inability to figure out how to tag the teams in `merge_allwinsloss_df` by conference properly. I'm sorry if this isn't overtly clear. I've been searching for help and racking my brain for days so any help would get greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

UPDATE: Here is a minimal example.

```
#Create a list of CFB winners and losers with weight given by point differential
merge_allwinsloss_ALT_df <- data.frame(matrix(c("CAL","HAW", 12, "TENN", "APP", 7, "LOU", "CHAR", 56, 
                                  "CMU", "HAW", 0, "WVU", "APP", 20 , "ARK", "TENN", 6, "CMU", "WVU", 7,
                                  "WVU", "JMU", 15, "IND", "MIN", 3, "IND", "HAW", 14, "FSU", "TCU", 2, 
                                  "TCU", "ARK", 14),
            nrow=12,ncol=3,byrow=TRUE))
colnames(merge_allwinsloss_ALT_df) <- c("winner", "loser", "weight")
merge_allwinsloss_ALT_df

#Create a list of CFB teams with conference associations
all_teams_by_conference_ALT_df<- data.frame(matrix(c("CAL","PAC", "HAW", "MAC", "TENN", "SEC", 
                                                     "APP", "SUN BELT", "LOU", "ACC", "CHAR", "FCS", 
                                                "CMU", "MAC", "WVU", "BIG 12", "ARK", "SEC", "JMU", "FCS",
                                                "IND", "BIG 10", "MIN", "BIG 10", "FSU", "ACC", "TCU",
                                                "BIG 12"),
                                              nrow=14,ncol=2,byrow=TRUE))
colnames(all_teams_by_conference_ALT_df) <- c("team", "conference")
all_teams_by_conference_ALT_df

# (attempt to) Plot the two data files using the first as the nodes and the # second as a reference file for coloring by conference. 

ggplot(data = merge_allwinsloss_ALT_df, aes(from_id = winner, to_id = loser)) +
  geom_net(aes(color = all_teams_by_conference_ALT_df), layout.alg = "fruchtermanreingold", 
           size = 2, labelon = TRUE, vjust = -0.6, ecolour = "grey80",
           directed = TRUE, fontsize = 3, ealpha = 0.5) +
  scale_color_brewer("Conference",
                     palette = "Paired") +
  xlim(c(-0.05, 1.05)) +
  theme_net() +
  theme(legend.position = "bottom")
```

I realize that something is off here but I just can't figure it out. Moreover, I'd like to set it up so that (a) all of the teams in the same conference that have played against each other share a common color for their edges and (b) weight the edges using the weight column in `merge_allwinsloss_df_ALT`.

Thank you for the help!

Comment: TEM and AAC are part of one conference? the dataframe is missing the header

Comment: It's more likely that we will be able to help you if you provide a [complete minimal reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to go along with your question. Something we can work from and use to show you how it might be possible to answer your question.

Comment: Sorry @HardikGupta. I have fixed the table problem. It now has headers. @EricFail, I receive this output when I try to run the plot:
 `Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (832): colour, from_id, to_id.` Thanks for your help.

Comment: @EricFail my apologies. This is my first time posting here and I did not understand what a complete minimal reproducible example was and you clearly linked it. The code above has been updated. I really do appreciate the help and patience.

Comment: It's all good. I appreciate the work you put into it! However, a _minimal_ example really help. Your _complete reproducible example_ has 600 lines of code. Any chance you could find an example of what you are looking for at [the `geomnet' package examples page](https://github.com/sctyner/geomnet) and rework that into a complete minimal reproducible example?

Comment: Sorry about that @EricFail. I have reproduced a similar example above. Its basically what I'm trying to do in a nutshell. Thanks!

Comment: Great work. And you got an answer within 10 minutes. Let us know if this answers your question and we will take it form there. Cheers.

Comment: Thanks @EricFail. I did follow up and I clearly did not do a good job explaining my intent. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You need to join the two tables together so that it's all in one data frame.

To add the conference of the winner, you'd do it as follows:

```
df1 <- merge(merge_allwinsloss_ALT_df,all_teams_by_conference_ALT_df, 
  by.x="winner",by.y="team",all.x=T)
```

To capture both the winning and losing teams' conferences, then I'd rename `df1$conference` to "conference_winner", and then perform the same merge again this time using `df1`, and `by.x="loser"`

Also, I'd suggest trying to use shorter names for your data frames. It doesn't make sense to type `merge_allwinsloss_ALT_df` over and over. Also `merge` is a function, so that compounds the problem by creating confusion when you use it in a name (see above where my code is `merge(merge...)` due your naming convention).

After that you can just map `color` and/or `fill` to `conference_winner` or `conference_loser`.

Comment: I think that I may have been not communicating well. I actually want to plot the vertices (`teams`) with directed edges (using from `winner` to `loser`) and color code them by conference. Also the teams that play against each other and are in the same conference share edges that have the same color.

Comment: I did something similar to what you stated before posting the original question but could not the the desired result. Melting the data while keeping `winner` and `loser` (and `weight`) static doubled my row numbers for obvious reasons. So I'm at a loss at what to do. Thanks again!